# Fetch value of a field from one entity to second entity based on the lookup field selected in second entity using Fetch XML

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, fetchxml

I am new to CRM. I have a requirement where I have an "account" entity and a "contact" entity. In contact form I have a lookup field for searching account name which is stored in account entity. When I select an organization through lookup, the contact number of that organization should be fetched and saved in another field in contact form. I need to do it with fetch XML.

Comment: Why does it need to be done with FetchXML? This would be possible to do with a BPF.

Comment: Yes Jonas I can do it with BPF or even workflows. I have done it using javascript oData. But now the requirement is to be done with fetchXML

Comment: Is this 2016 or later ? FetchXML should be left behind to rot, WebAPI is there now to make our life easier and our code work better. The only answer I can come up with is "tell your boss to stop wasting your time with FetchXML". More seriously: SOAP endpoints are going to vanish and only the WebAPI will stay, so it's not worth the effort.

Comment: You can still use FetchXML with the WebAPI endpoint... ;)

Answer (score -1):

Option 1: You can do a no-code solution by [mapping fields](http://crm.fullscope.com/save-time-entering-data-into-crm-by-mapping-fields-between-records/) between account & contact.

[image]

Option 2: If you don't want a physical copy of field value in both entity, use Quick view form of Account lookup to just display the fields in contact without storing redundant data.

Option 3: If you still want to store the value onchange of account, [retrieve it & set it in contact field](https://arunpotti.wordpress.com/2014/11/15/retrieve-records-using-fetch-xml-java-script-in-crm-201113/). This step by step guide will help you to build fetchxml & use it in JS. Your question doesn't say if you are stuck in query or any error.

Comment: Wouldn't this only apply to new contacts created from the account ? OP wants to pick a parent account from the contact and copy a field over (IIRC)

Comment: Thanks Arun I tried your solution. But Alex also got it right. The same thing is happening.

Comment: did you explore solution 2 & 3 ? 1st will not work in all scenarios