# How to get option Set Value from Parent entity and Set that value in option set in child entity.

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I Have `Entity A` and `Entity B` with `N:1 Relationship` through lookup field called `lookupToB`.
In `Entity A` and `Entity B` I have option set field called `grouping` with using same global option set value.
What I need to do is, I want to set value for field `grouping` in Entity A same with field grouping B
if the relationship exist.

I know we can use Workflow for this, but I prefer to use javascript.

I can get `name`,`id`and `entityType` of the Entity B and populated in one custom field in Entity A by using this code.

```
    //get value in lookup(Entity B)
    var LookuptoB = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("lookuptob").getValue()[0].name;
    var LookuptoBID = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("lookuptob").getValue()[0].id;
    var LookuptoBType = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("lookuptob").getValue()[0].entityType;

    //Set value into custom field A of Entity A
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("custom_fielda").setValue(LookuptoB + LookuptoBID + LookuptoBType);
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("custom_fielda").setSubmitMode("always");
```

But, I cannot get any others attributes of Entity B. For example:

```
//Get option set value in Entity B
var optionSetB = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("lookuptob").getValue()[0].new_grouping;

//Set option set Value in Entity A
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_grouping").setValue(optionSetB);
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_grouping").setSubmitMode("always");
```

I m thinking this is not correct way to get and set value for option set field [Boolean and OptionSet Attribute methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx#BKMK_getOption). But when I tried to get others attributes besides `name`,`id` and `entityType` of the Entity B and populated in one custom field in Entity A, the value display in that custom field in `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Few facts:

1. Lookup field is a relationship, will have parent entity name, foreign key guid & display name of that parent record
2. To pull extra attributes of that parent entity (ex.grouping picklist) you have to make a sdk call to retrieve & set in child entity
3. If you have the lookup (n:1 relationship) you don’t need custom attribute to store concatenation values
4. There are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46395134) to achieve this

Comment: Thanks Arun, If u dont mind can you share how to make a sdk call to retrieve & set in child entity. For option 4 weird thing is when I am using Mapping functionality I cannot find my grouping field in Source and Target Entity.

Comment: @xChaax  search online for samples - odata or webapi based on your CRM version

Comment: One more thing for the mapping functionality is it only apply for a new record of entity A ? Or for existing record when I change the value of lookuptob, will its reflect the value in grouping picklist in A based on grouping pick list in B ?

Comment: @xChaax Mapping is only for new record

Comment: Dont think can use mapping because my entity is N:1 relationship. Everthing I created from Entity A then fill in lookup value of entity B.

Comment: @xChaax mapping works only when creating child from inside parent record.. check other solutions like quick view.. don’t forget to upvote if it helps you..