# How to add Quick Create Forms and Pre-Populating Fields

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, xrm

I have two entity account and contact..i want to add Quick Create Forms of contact entity inside account entity...and i want to pre-Poulating the fields based on selected record of account...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46395134/7920473

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need Javascripting. You can do so without code.
2. From Account to Contact MS CRM gives out of Box Relationship
3. This you can see from Account to Contact in 1:N see Image below
   [image]
4. Now when you open this relationship you can see mapping i.e Fields which can be moved from Account to contact when you create a new contact. You can add your fields as well.
   [image]
5. Now In Account add a subgrid for contact.
   [image]
6. you have to also check if your contact Entity allows Quick create. If not allow quick create
   [image]
7. If you follow all the steps you get desired result
   [image]